# Images rendering everytime translateY animation happens. Only in Chrome

Tags: css, animation, transform, transition

Here is the code example: http://codepen.io/fornyhucker/pen/zlxtu?editors=110

When hover on "winter image" last two images will be sharp until translateY animation finished. That happens only in Chrome and only with images that going after animated element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `z-index:1` to  `div > img`  and then `z-index:2;` to `div > span`. I had same problem in the past with absolute positioned div and `z-index` solved my problem.

**[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKxAr)**

Comment: Did you have same problem with 'scale' animation? Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/fornyhucker/pen/bEgiL)

Comment: @fornyhucker which is the problem? In chrome I don't have this problem.. in the demo seems to be ok

Comment: @fornyhucker let me know if you have other problems.. I'm here to help you

Comment: It happens first time you hover any image, all other images became sharp(same as it was in original question), but it back to normal only after ~10 secs. Then if you hover an image it will go back to normal when animation ends. Do you see it?